# 2 Loops with different step from two files

Tags: python, python-2.7

lets consider we have

```
file1
```

with some lines

and

```
file2
```

also some string lines

i want to loop both files together for each line from **file1** (1 line) i loop 100 line from **file2** ,also note that the lines of file1 can cause some exceptions so we need to pass a line if it causes a problem

i just want simple and clean code and thank you for the help in advance

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: It seems you understand the logic of what you want to accomplish but are hoping for someone to write out the solution for you... Would be better if you provided some input on an attempt you made and any issues you have come across to add some value to this post.

Comment: thank you for the undertanding but my main problem is how to loop 1 i for each 100 line in j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through two lists simultaneously by using the zip function in python.

As for errors, you can have your for loop recognize a specific error (for example, a ValueError) and then respond accordingly. You will want to change the code below to your specific error and tell if what to do when that happens.

**Update**: In order to loop through one line of file1 and X lines of file2, use zip twice. This example code loops through one line of file1 and 3 lines of file2, printing them next to each other. You can simply change "3" to "100" for your actual data.

**Update 2**: Now the code simply removes any lines in file1 that are giving you an error. Because I don't know what errors you are receiving, in my code it was easiest to just add an integer, 3, to the file and remove the lines that aren't strings. I have provided comments on how to change this part to reflect your errors. Because the lines are removed, it prints out the next viable line in file1 with the original lines in file2.

```py
file1 = 'example \n text'
file1 = file1.split()
file1.append(3)
file1.append('extra')

file2 = 'this \n is \n some \n more \n example \n text \n words \n words \n words \n more \n words \n here'
file2 = file2.split()

#For one line in file1, this will iterate through 3 lines in file2 
#Prints out both
print('Original: ')
for i,j in zip(file1, zip(*(iter(file2),) * 3)):
    print(i,j)

#For one line in file1, this will iterate through 3 lines in file2
#Deletes lines in file1 that result in an error
print('\nNew: ')
for i,j in zip(file1, zip(*(iter(file2),) * 3)):
    if type(i) == str: #Change to "try:"
        pass
    else: #Change to "except ValueError:" or whatever error you are receiving 
        file1.remove(i)    

#For one line in file1, this will iterate through 3 lines in file2
#Prints out both, this time with the erroneous lines removed 
for i,j in zip(file1, zip(*(iter(file2),) * 3)):
    print(i,j)
```

Comment: thank you for this but the problem is how can i loop for each i line 100 lines in j

Comment: I have edited my answer to fix this for you. Please mark it as accepted if it now works as you want it to :)

Comment: Finally ! thank you , more more thing : lets suppose " i " throw an exception how can i jump to the next i without loosing the 100 line

Comment: You can simply do what you want with j after the except ValueError section of the code. Just change the last line there to do what you want with j. For example, except ValueError: print(j). Just make sure to change the error to whatever error you're encountering.

Comment: i dont want to lose the 100 data lines in j , i just want to loop them in the next i : exemple" i "number 2 throwed an exception . i want to loop that 100 line of data ( j ) that was supposed to be looped in the 2nd " i " in the 3rd " i "

Comment: kelsey btw j = j.rstrip("\n") dosent work ! any solution  ??

Comment: I added another update for you that removes the lines that are giving you errors, and prints out the same group from file2 with the next line in file1. I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with j.rstrip("\n"). I would recommend posting another question for this, but this time with example code for others to troubleshoot.

Comment: about your print('\nNew: ') code in the last update can i check, remove, and print in the same time ? because i dont want to loop twice